# switch to control unique table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I just add a switch in my cell and I would like to make each switch to get the nique cell's information and control the unique cell. my codes are below:

in the  method of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I created a switch

```
 UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        cell.accessoryView = switchView;
        [switchView setOn:NO animated:NO];
[switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

then I write method for switch. It's all working fine, but I cannot get the switch's cell

```
- (void) switchChanged:(id)sender withIdentifier:(NSString*)locationName{
    UISwitch* switchControl = sender;
    if (switchControl.on) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.AlarmsTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        NSLog(@"the switch is on for row number: %d",indexPath.row);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"switch off");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the concept of tags here.
Give your switches a tag, usually the cells indexpath

```
switchView.tag=indexPath.row;
```

and in your function, use the tag

```
int switchTag=[sender tag];
```

and this will be your cell

```
NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:switchTag inSection:0] ;
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];
```

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath:switchTag, should be indexPath.switchTag?

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath need to pass an indexPath, not a integer.

Comment: it's a pity apple do not have a visible interface for creating the NSIdexPath for the condition of multiple sections. I  tried the code NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:switchTag inSection:0] ; but get error message

Comment: it actually works! even I do not see any Creating Index Paths
indexPathWithIndex:
indexPathWithIndexes:length:
initWithIndex:
initWithIndexes:length:
which including inSection, while i copy and paste, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
switchView.tag = indexPath.row;
```

And in switch event method do this:

```
UISwitch *tswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
//tswitch.tag; is your row.
```

If you have a single section in tableView then do this:

```
NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: tswitch.tag inSection:0] ;
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: myIP];
```

Comment: While I successfully get the row number, how can I get the cell with index path?

Comment: @JimLiu you cant with this solution. See my answer for how to make that possible.

Comment: i got 2 sections in the table view

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Your SwitchView 

    switchView.tag = indexPath.row; 
}

-(void) switchChanged:(id)sender withIdentifier:(NSString*)locationName
{
    UISwitch* switchControl = (UISwitch *)sender;

    if(switchControl.on) 
    {
        //NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.AlarmsTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        NSLog(@"the switch is on for row number: %d",switchControl.tag);
    }
    else
    {
       NSLog(@"switch off");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I humbly disagree with the "tag"-solution. Sure it works if you only have one section, but it's not "the best" solution.

You should instead subclass UITableViewCell and have your switch there. Then the cell "handles" the switch, and preferably tell it's delegate (Which you create yourself, and set to the ViewController that is handling the tableView) that

> `switchChangedTo:(BOOL)onOrOff forCell:(YourSubclassCell*)cell`

Then you can easily determine the indexpath for the cell via the tableView-method `indexPathForCell`

Comment: I see. I will just create a sub-class of the cell and add the method and set the delegate to see if it's working.